# jQuery .GET method

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, get

Here is an example of the JSON string I am taking from Online

```
{
  "meta":{
      "course":"fgf",
       "course":"ffff",
       "course":"feeef",


  },
  "data":{
    "course":"ff",
    "sections":[
      {
        "section":"001",
        "day":"Thursday",
        "date":"2014-08-07",
        "start_time":"9:00 AM",
        "end_time":"11:30 AM",
        "location":"ff",
        "notes":""
      },
                {
        "section":"002",
        "day":"Thursday",
        "date":"2014-08-07",
        "start_time":"9:00 AM",
        "end_time":"11:30 AM",
        "location":"ff",
        "notes":""
      }


    ]
  }
}
```

The problem arises with the "data" word. If I want to obtain everything, I simple write down console.log(obj) if I want to get the meta object, I write down console.log(obj.meta) but IF i want to get the DATA, I have to write down obj.data but that doesn't work! nor does obj['data'] . It makes no sense to me! Isn't that an object too? How can I deal with this situation? Also, I can only use get method

Here is my get code,

```
  $.get(link,function(obj){
          console.log(obj.data);
```

Valid Inputs:

MTE
111

MATH 
118

MTE
120

Comment: You are missing a `,` between the objects in `data` . Is that a copy/paste error ?

Comment: Sorry, I lost a comma in process of removing personal information

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean? What happens? We can't really help you of you don't provide a proper description of the problem.

Comment: Example structure still doesn’t make sense, since you have _two_ `}` after `{ "meta":{`, which means `data` is not even on the same level as `meta`.

Comment: It gives an empty object. Sorry CBroe , there was a lot of info which I removed and it gave an extra bracket. I rechecked eerythiing seems fine now. The data always gets highlighted in sublimetext whereas meta doesn't

Comment: Just log the whole object to console, then you should be able to easily inspect it and see its actual structure.

Comment: Yes. I did. The whole object gets executed. If I console obj.meta, I get the correct result but an empty array for obj.data!

Comment: Well then show us a live example please where we can have a look at it. (So far this makes little sense … `data` is not even an _array_ in the structure you have shown, but an object …)

Comment: Okay, ill upload it in jsfiddler

Comment: Maybe the property name contains a space or some other strange character?

Comment: I couldn't upload jsfiddler cause i realized i need to sign up for that. I editted my post. Please tell me once you are done analysing.

Comment: No, you do not. jsfiddle.net. No login, completely free.

Comment: I just googled how to use it! I thought i needed to log in

Comment: Also VALID inputs are Name: MATH Number :118 , MTE 120 , MTE 140 , MTE 111 . There are obviously more but try working with these inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like you are trying to use this API here, https://github.com/uWaterloo/api-documentation/blob/master/v2/courses/subject_catalog_number_examschedule.md

When testing this with one of the sets of default parameters they provide on that docs page (subject `CS`, number `486`), it works fine – and when I change the number to something else like `1234567890`, it returns an *empty* `data` object, because there *is* no data for that non-existent number … as `meta.message` clearly states in such a case: `No data returned`

So it looks like you have just searched with parameters for which there is no data … and did not pay enough attention to the response you were getting.

http://jsfiddle.net/mj3Lo5x2/

**EDIT:**
OK, scratch all that … you originally posted this JS code in your question,

```
  $("#howdy").click(function(){
    var subject = $("#name").value;
    var number = $("#number").value;
```

– this does **not** get you the values of the input fields, because `.value` is a method of the pure HTMLInputElement objects, but you don’t have those here, you have jQuery objects – and with those, you need to use `.val()` to get the current contents of an input field. By using `.value` instead, you most likely got `undefined` for both those variables, so that you where effectively requesting `/v2/courses/undefined/undefined/examschedule.json` from the API … way to send everyone on a wild goose chase! Next time please do some basic debugging by checking if the values your script uses are actually what you *assume* they are!

Comment: Oh no! I searched for MTE 120 , which i know is a valid course. You must enter a valid course in the university. I am getting the overall data but not obj.data.

Comment: All three combinations of subject and number that you mentioned in the edit of your question produce non-empty `data` objects, see http://jsfiddle.net/mj3Lo5x2/2/ – logging `obj.data` to console produces results in all three cases, as you can see.

Comment: I appreciate your effort for helping me. I was getting the responses for meta and obj and I didn't realize the val and value was wrong.